# How can I get scrollViewDidScrollToTop to work in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I think the title explains it all. I want to be notified when a user scrolls to the top of a tableview.

I've tried the following with no luck and even added a UIScrollViewDelegate to the .h file.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"ScrolledToTop");
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit**: I can get it to call if I press the status bar. But not if I scroll to the top. Weird... could it have something to do with the tableview bouncing when it reaches the top?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What happens if you try this?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
        NSLog(@"At the top");
}
```

Comment: Man, that is so inefficient.  It gets called like crazy.  Isn't there a better way?

Comment: There isn't a better way. It has to check every single time the scroll view moves one point. The only way to check less would be to check when the user lifts their finger off after having scrolled, but then you wouldn't be notified right aways. Depends on what you're wanting to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 ) {
    NSLog(@"Showing top cell");

}
```

Is that close enough?

Comment: Actually, it's not. I want it to call when it reaches the top of the tableview header. Not the first cell. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

The `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` delegate method will do the trick but it gets called each time the scrollview moves a point. A less *hyperactive* alternative could be this:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>){
    if targetContentOffset.memory.y == 0.0 {
       println("Reached the Top")
}
```

It lets the delegate know the scrollView will reach the top before it actually gets there, and because `targetContentOffset` is a pointer you can change its value to adjust where the scrollview finishes its scrolling animation.

Answer (score 0):

Two more options that might be simpler based on your situation are:

First, if you're trying to detect the result of an *animation* only, triggered either by animating `contentOffset` yourself or by making a call to UITableView [`scrollToRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:), or UICollectionView [`scrollToItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:), implement

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // You're now at the end of the scrolling animation
}
```

This will not not be called after a manual scroll with your finger, which may or may not be helpful sometimes.

Second, if you're trying to do something like infinite scrolling, where you refresh the list when you get to the top, or load another page of results when you get to the bottom, an easy way to do it is to just use make the call in your data source [`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) which might save you the need to implement the delegate all together.

Answer (score -1):

Do it in Swift:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print(scrollView.contentOffset.y) 
}
```